# With the characteristic equation, how do I get this solution?

Tags: recurrence-relations

There is one part of the characteristic equation I don't quite understand. If I've been given the following equation:

$$
T(n)=
\begin{cases}
1,\quad if\ n=1\\
T(n-1)+n+1
\end{cases}
$$

Then, you simply it to this:

$$
T(n)-T(n-1)=n+1=(1+n)^11^n
$$

This makes sense to me, but how do you go from that to this:

$$
(x-1)(x-1)^2=0
$$

Then to this:

$$
\exists c_1, c_2, c_3 \in R
$$
$$
\forall n \in N
$$
$$
T(n)=c_11^n+c_2n1^n+c_3n^21^n
$$

I can figure out the rest from here, but I don't understand these steps. I know it's probably easier to use iteration to solve this problem, but I want to have a better understanding of how the characteristics equation works.

Comment: Should one of your $T(n)$s in the first equation be $T(n-1)$?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta ah, yes. thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

Since $T_n = T_{n-1} +n+1$ we have $T_{n+1} = T_n + n+2 \implies T_{n+1} = 2T_n-T_{n-1}+1$
Applying this method again we have $T_{n+2} = 2T_{n+1}-T_n+1 \implies T_{n+2}=3T_{n+1}-3T_n+T_{n-1}$  or 
$$
T_n=3T_{n-1}-3T_{n-2}+T_{n-3}
$$
This is a linear homogeneous relation with constant coefficients and the characteristic polynomial is $$p(x) = x^3-3x^2+3x-1 = (x-1)^3$$
It has one root $x=1$ of order $3$ and so $T_n=c_1+c_2n+c_3n^2$